# How to bulk update to realtime database faster with admin sdk?

Tags: java, python, firebase-realtime-database

I need to update a set of data periodically to my realtime database(approx 1100-1200 data) which may or may not exist on the database.

I have used python and java admin sdk for firebase. First I tried to update the data using a loop, but it seems tremendously slow as it takes 40+ mins for updating 1100 data. I can not batch update as it will overwrite my existing data. I need a way to update data inside every node and if the data doesn't exist then simply create a new node.

I've been doing it like this, but this is taking forever

```
for data in datalist:
    if data.id and data.uid:
        obj = {
            'name': data.name,
            'id': data.id
        }

        grd = {}
        grd['basic'] = data.gender
        ref = root.child(data.uid).update(obj)
        ref = root.child(data.uid).child('basic').update(grd)
```

I thought that I can download my whole database from the realtime database and modify it. Then I can just update the whole data. But currently my database size is about 4 mb, which is growing pretty fast. So even if I do that, it will keep getting harder in future.

Is there any alternative way for this kind of batch updates? Or if there is any way where I can reduce the updating time to 5~10 mins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I can think of is to use multi-location updates as shown [here](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/09/introducing-multi-location-updates-and_86.html). In there's you're creating deep paths to the exact properties that you want to update, so you can apply granular updates to anything in the database. In JavaScript syntax your current write as a multi-location update would look like this:

```
root.update({
  `/${data.uid}/name`: data.name,
  `/${data.uid}/id`: data.id,
  `/${data.uid}/basic/basic`: data.gender
})
```

Using this approach will reduce the network overhead, as you're combining multiple calls into one. On the other hand, processing the update *may* require more time on the server, as it needs to keep all updates in memory before committing them to disk. So you'll want to measure the performance impact of using multi-location updates.

I'd recommend combining say 100 updates into a single call, and then measuring the performance difference between that and the 100 individual calls.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion and sorry for the late reply. I tried this solution, it makes the upload really fast (2500 data updates took ~7 secs). But it overwrites my existing data instead of updating it. Is there anything I'm doing wrong? I followed the java solution that was provided on that link.

Comment: What I show in my answer should update the specific paths that are passed to `update` and nothing outside of those. If that's not what's happening for you, you're indeed likely doing something wrong. It's impossible for me to say wht that is without seeing the code you used.

Comment: Apparently I found out what I was doing wrong, I was updating the values for a specific node which was overwriting that whole node with that data. But I think this solution is the best with some modifications. Thanks a lot :D